# Hangman in Java throws ArrayIndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, string, for-loop, while-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

My programs throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException at this segment of code: `temp1 = temp.replace('-', temp.charAt(p));` I'm trying to get the index of the same letter (after comparing inputted letter and word) and removing the '-' to show that the user has guessed correctly.**  **I've been trying for hours to no avail. I think the problem lies in my loops. Thanks for the answers :) if I violated anything, please forgive me.

> ```
> run:
> -----
> Enter a letter:
> a
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
> ```
>
> 3
>         at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
>         at Hangman.main(Hangman.java:34)
>       Java Result: 1

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hangman {

    public static void main (String [] args){

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String word = "Sample";
    String temp = null;
    String temp1 = null;
    String letter = null;
    int n;
    int m=0;
    int p = 0;

         for (n = 0; n<word.length(); n++){

                temp = word.replaceAll(word, "-"); //replaces the String word with "-" and prints
                System.out.print(temp); 

           }

         while (m<=5){ //the player can only guess incorrectly 5 times
                System.out.println("\nEnter a letter:");
                letter = sc.nextLine();

                letter.toLowerCase();

                if (word.contains(letter) == true){
                    p = word.indexOf(letter);
                    temp1 = temp.replace('-', temp.charAt(p)); //if the word contains the letter, "-" is replaced by the letter.
                    System.out.print(temp1);
                }

                else {
                    System.out.print("\nMissed: "+letter); //if not, Missed: +the given letter
                    m++; //to count for incorrect guesses
                }    

                System.out.print(temp1);
        }


                System.out.println("Game Over.");
         }

    }
```

Comment: temp1 = temp.replace('-', temp.charAt(p)); In this line, instead of temp.charAt(p) use word.charAt(p) because temp is ----- and not sample when you have written temp = word.replaceAll(word, "-"); This will help you.....

Comment: Ah yes, I can see now. So I tried replacing temp1 = temp.replace('-', temp.charAt(p)); to temp1 = temp.replace('-',word.charAt(p));.

But this is what happens:  
------
Enter a letter:
a
aa
Enter a letter:

It prints just until the index. I can't seem to implement the "char by char print" properly, which I think might solve this problem.

Comment: It is printing twice because you are writing  System.out.print(temp1); twice that is in while loop if (m <=5) and at the end of this loop also (just before Game Over.). Remove the one above System.out.println("Game Over. "); and this will solve this problem also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.....
This will solve your problem...!!

package beans;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hangman {

```
public static String replace(String str, int index, char replace){     
    if(str==null){
        return str;
    }else if(index<0 || index>=str.length()){
        return str;
    }
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    chars[index] = replace;
    return String.valueOf(chars);       
}

public static void main (String [] args){

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String word = "Sample";
    String temp = "";
    String letter = null;

    int n;
    int m=0;
    int p = 0;

    for (n = 0; n<word.length(); n++){
        temp = temp + word.replaceAll(word, "-"); //replaces the String word with "-" and prints
    }

    System.out.print(temp); 

    while (m <= 5){ //the player can only guess incorrectly 5 times
        System.out.println("\nEnter a letter:");
        letter = sc.nextLine();

        letter.toLowerCase();
        if (word.contains(letter) == true){
            p = word.indexOf(letter);
            temp = replace(temp, p , word.charAt(p)); //if the word contains the letter, "-" is replaced by the letter.
            System.out.println(temp);
        }

        else {
            System.out.print("\nMissed: "+letter); //if not, Missed: +the given letter
            m++; //to count for incorrect guesses
        }    
    }
    System.out.println("Game Over.");
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

When you do this:

```
temp = word.replaceAll(word, "-");
```

...you are setting `temp` to be just "-", and not (for example) "----". To see why, consider if `word` is "hello"; then this line looks like:

```
temp = "hello".replaceAll("hello", "-");
```

So then later you are assuming that `temp` is as long as `word` is, because you find an index in `word` and try to access that character in `temp`. But `temp` is only one character long, hence the exception.

```
p = word.indexOf(letter);
temp1 = temp.replace('-', temp.charAt(p));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (word.contains(letter) == true){
                p = word.indexOf(letter);
                temp1 = temp.replace('-', temp.charAt(p)); //if the word contains the letter, "-" is replaced by the letter.
                System.out.print(temp1);
            }
```

the  word.indexOf(letter); return index of letter if that latter is present in string otherwise -1. that's why  you are getting Exception.

Comment: This is wrong, it excludes the last index in the word. An array's bounds are ``0 <= i < length`` or ``0 <= i <= length - 1``

Comment: Yep, this doesn't solve the problem. It removes the last index of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud check documentation for replaceAll() method.Cause you are using it wrong.

> replaceAll(String regex, String replacement) 
>             Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.

You putting whole string into regex parameter

If you do `myString.replaceAll("\\.","-");`   (use double backslash to specify regex)  will replace any character beside newline with "-" check into regex.  [Regullar expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested, but I'm still stuck at it printing just until the returned index.